# Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses

Tags: laravel, email, office365

I'm getting this error when sending an email via Office 365 from a Laravel system.
But the peculiarity is that it is random. It is not a mail configuration problem. Sometimes it works, sometimes it gives the error.
I think Office 365 is doing a lock. But the error message confuse me.
Has it happened to someone? Thanks!

Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: this works on localhost and live server throw this error?

Comment: Live server....

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that you configure the mail correctly

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= //your username
MAIL_PASSWORD= //your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

according to [this issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/797) discussions, it seems that it may related to WHM/Cpanel Users-- there is a tweak setting that may be tripping you up and redirecting outgoing email connections to localhost (which is then rejecting your connection).

https://features.cpanel.net/topic/change-fka-smtp-tweak-behavior-to-encourage-correct-user-behavior

Answer (score 0):

if your are using GoDaddy Linux hosting try this:

mail_mailer=smtp

mail_host=localhost   //using localhost cause we are in the same domin

mail_port=25

mail_username=       //keep it empty

mail_password=          //keep it empty

mail_encryption=         // keep it empty

mail_from_address=username@udomin.com//this same for your email username

mail_from_name=stackoverflow // any name

*see we are use this setting because we are in the same serve*